# Serving videos from Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, amazon-s3

If I host video or any other media content on Amazon S3, how can I use ASP.net Membership to enforce access rights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**S3 permissions**

Make sure that you **don't** grant anonymous read access to your S3 content.

**Asp.net security**

Setup your asp.net pages so that only logged in users or those with appropriate permissions can visit them

**Urls to S3 content**

On your Asp.net pages, generate time limited urls to your content on S3. eg Using the [AWS SDK for .net](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) to create a pre-signed url in vb.net:

```
Dim AWSKey As String = "AWS_Key"
Dim AWSSecretKey As String = "AWS_SecretKey"

Using client As AmazonS3 = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWSKey, AWSSecretKey)

    Dim req = New Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest With { _
                   .BucketName = bucket, _
                   .Key = key, _
                   .Protocol = Model.Protocol.HTTPS, _
                   .Verb = Model.HttpVerb.GET, _
                   .Expires = Now.AddDays(ExpiryInDays).AddSeconds(secs) }

    Dim url As String = client.GetPreSignedURL(req)
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks dear, will need to do some work on how to generate time-limited urls. If you know any please give me links.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - Download the AWS SDK for dotnet at http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/. It has example code on how to do this and easy to use libraries to do just that. I'll update my answer shortly with a sample